# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in IntelliJ

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have opened a AndroidStudio Project in my IntelliJ. I would like to work with IntelliJ in the future so I like to switch.

But I get an 
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
Error when building and I have no idea what is the solution for. I tried several hints already, but now I need to ask.

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        manifestPlaceholders = [versionCode:"161", versionName:"2.37"]
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"RELEASE\""
        }
        full {
            buildConfigField "String", "appID", "\"FULL\""
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
}
```

Under 'Project Structure' -> Project SDK I have set my Java SDK 1.8.

Can someone help / give me a hint ?

Comment: Does it build from the command line Gradle? Can you add info or debug options to get more details about the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your TargetedSdkVersion is less than compileSdkVersion. Make targeted to 27 and try sync.

Comment: I treid, but still same issue.